# No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 2,

Tags: typescript, react-redux

I have `store.js` file

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from "redux";
import reducerADD from "../reducer/reducerADD"

export const store = createStore(combineReducers({ reducerADD}));
```

When I change format in `store.tsx` I'm getting an Error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(reducers: ReducersMapObject<{ reducerADD: { lastName: string; firstName: string; password: string; email: string; }[]; }, any>): Reducer<{ reducerADD: { lastName: string; firstName: string; password: string; email: string; }[]; }, AnyAction>', gave the following error.
    Type '(state: never[] | undefined, action: action) => { lastName: string; firstName: string; password: string; email: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<{ lastName: string; firstName: string; password: string; email: string; }[], any>'.
      Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
        Type '{ lastName: string; firstName: string; password: string; email: string; }[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'never[] | undefined'.
          Type '{ lastName: string; firstName: string; password: string; email: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
            Type '{ lastName: string; firstName: string; password: string; email: string; }' is not assignable to type 'never'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(reducers: ReducersMapObject<{ reducerADD: { lastName: string; firstName: string; password: string; email: string; }[]; }, AnyAction>): Reducer<{ reducerADD: { lastName: string; firstName: string; password: string; email: string; }[]; }, AnyAction>', gave the following error.
    Type '(state: never[] | undefined, action: action) => { lastName: string; firstName: string; password: string; email: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'Reducer<{ lastName: string; firstName: string; password: string; email: string; }[], AnyAction>'.
      Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
        Type '{ lastName: string; firstName: string; password: string; email: string; }[] | undefined' is not assignable to type 'never[] | undefined'.
          Type '{ lastName: string; firstName: string; password: string; email: string; }[]' is not assignable to type 'never[]'.
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: What is the definition of `reducerADD`?

Comment: `const reducerADD = (state = [], action:action) =>{
    switch (action.type) {
        case "ADD":
            return [...state, ...[action.add]];
        default:
            return state;
    }
}`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The state needs to be abit more strongly typed. Its trying to cast your initial state from type `any` to type `never`.

When creating the default state for the data you should define an interface for your state, here's an example for a todo list array:

```
interface IAppState {
  toDoList: any[];
}
const initialState: IAppState = {
  toDoList: []
};

export default function reducer(state = initialState, action) {}
```

Answer (score 12):

For future googlers:

This is also the error returned if you forget to call your function with the same inputs as used in the function definition.

Example:

```
const handleSaveAll = (currRow: MyItem, fileToUpload: File | undefined) => {
    //all the stuff the function does
});
```

The Error:

```
<Button className={style.btnSave} onClick={handleSaveAll}>
```

The Fix:

```
<Button className={style.btnSave} onClick={() => handleSaveAll(currRow, fileToUpload)}>
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the error comes from a loop malformed

```
    cards.map(card => {
        <EasyGridItem cols={ card.cols }>
            <BandcampDailyCard card={ card } /> 
        </EasyGridItem>
    })
```

Just replaced the `{}` for `()`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, Then I found out I was using `console.table` for an object, hence I changed it to `console.log` for console.log the object. And it solved my poblem